# Volatile is extra or not?

Tags: c++, volatile

This is a sample function(C++) of [alglib](https://www.alglib.net) library used for equal checking:

```
ae_bool ae_fp_eq(double v1, double v2) {
    /* IEEE-strict floating point comparison */
    volatile double x = v1;
    volatile double y = v2;
    return x==y;
}
```

What is the reason for using `volatile` in this code?

What's wrong if removing it?

Comment: It appears to be an attempt to force the compiler not to carry the double in a register that may have more precision than a double in memory.

Comment: @Eljay Your comment is worth an answer.

Comment: @cigien The data format for a specific compiler is defined, even if it's implementation defined. So the values are equal if they are identical in the compiler's representation. Do you see a false-positive or false-negative answer to the question of being the same value?

Comment: Note that ALGLIB seems to rely in `volatile` enough to explicitly place expectations on how compilers perform optimizations (that they should, by all means, already comply with): from the [ALGLIB C++ Manual - 3.4 Optimization settings](https://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#gs_compatibility_opt), _"ALGLIB is compatible with any kind of optimizing compiler as long as: **volatile** modifier is correctly handled (i.e. compiler does **not** optimize volatile reads/writes), AND optimized code correctly handles IEEE special values"_.

Comment: @harper hmm, I suppose it's fine here. I just instinctively reacted to the code comparing doubles :p